# Too many values to unpack list of list

Tags: python

```
import random
import re

requestResponseList = [
[r'.*to Paris ?(.*)',
 ["We apologise, but all our services to Paris {0} have been cancelled!"],
 ["We are sorry, but all our flights on {0} to Paris are fully booked!"],
 ["There are no available flights {0} to Paris! Please accept our apologies."]
 ]
]


def analyze(statement):
 for pattern, responses in requestResponseList:
    match = re.match(pattern, statement.rstrip(".!?"))
    if match:
        response = random.choice(responses)
        if match.group(1):
            return response.format(*[(match.group(1))])
        return response.format(*[""])


def main():
statement = "What would be the first available flight to Paris next year?"
print(analyze(statement))

if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

This returns a  too many values to unpack (expected 2) error. After googling solutions i replaced

```
for pattern, responses in requestResponseList :
```

with this:

```
for pattern, responses in enumerate(requestResponseList):
```

This still produces an error: TypeError: first argument must be string or compiled pattern.

The very odd thing is that this code (enumerate omitted) a week ago. Could this be a Python version issue?

Comment: `requestResponseDict` is a list, not a dictionary. Why did you apply `enumerate()` you are trying to list your pattern and expected responses, not produce a number for each item.

Comment: The construction of this "dictionary" is both confusing and misleading. Dictionaries should be enclosed in curly braces {} not brackets [ ]. Also not sure why putting each item in its own list was necessary...

Comment: Try taking the `len(requestResponseDict)` and that will give you a hint as to the ValueError.

Comment: This `requestResponseDict ` is not a dict. you've made a list of lists.

Comment: Saying it's a list doesn't help me. I accidentally name the variables dict.How can i get this working?

Comment: @bob9123 well, for starters, it's a list with a single item, *another list*, which contains 4 elements, the first being a string, and the rest being single-elements lists, each of those elements being a string. It is totally unclear what you expect `for pattern, responses in requestResponseList:` to do, and this code would have failed with any Python version.

Comment: I suspect you want to have the "responses" all in one single list, not in many single-element lists. That would make sense, but you haven't really told us exactly what this is suppose to do, so I can only go by context and what your variable names imply.

Comment: `(*[(match.group(1))])`    oh my god....

Comment: @Reishin Looool

Comment: [Catch the exception](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and inspect/print relevant data to see what might be going on.

Comment: always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other usefull informations.

Answer (score 1):

List is incorrect constructed - you have three sublists with single strings inside but it has to be one sublist with three strings

```
requestResponseList = [
  [r'.*to Paris ?(.*)',
    [
      "We apologise, but all our services to Paris {0} have been cancelled!",
      "We are sorry, but all our flights on {0} to Paris are fully booked!",
      "There are no available flights {0} to Paris! Please accept our apologies."
    ]
  ]
]
```

And now it works for me.

---

I don't know why you use `*[...]` if it works without `*[...]`

```
        if match.group(1):
            return response.format( match.group(1) )
        return response.format( "" )
```